# isapi_redirect with iis and ssl

Tags: iis, tomcat, redirect

I've got iis redirecting http traffic to a tomcat server using isapi_redirect. I need to get it working with ssl, how can I do this?

If I enable ssl with iis and try to go to `https://domain/page.html` (a static page) everything works correctly, but when I go to `https://domain/app` (set up for isapi_redirect), I get a 401.5 status code (Authorization failed by ISAPI/CGI application.)

My workers.properties.minimal file:

```
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8011
```

tomcat server.xml contains:

```
<Connector port="8011" redirectPort="8443" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: 10 years later
Exact same question...